# Accessing https page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, https

I am currently adding an aspx page to my web site (.net) where my clients can insert credit card details. 
I would like to give access for that page from several pages only (lets call them a.aspx and b.aspx) and if someone tries to access this page from c.aspx he won't be able to do so.
Is there a way to limit the redirect to a page for few pages only?

I've tried to check at the page event what is the source of the call, with the "sender" object, however I am not sure it the right way to go.

Hope the question is clear enough.

Comment: Can you add to the question what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to know to do this is the [referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer).
The referer is, briefly, the page that brought you to the page you are currently at.

I believe this should get the referrer for ASP.net

```
Request.Server["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

Then you can just check and see if the referer matches your desired origins. However, I'm not sure about the ease/prevalence of referer spoofing, or if it even exists.

Comment: I supposed as much, which is why I made sure to mention it as a possible security concern.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is - have a look at the [HttpWebRequest.Referer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.referer.aspx) property.

Using this you can see from which page the request to c.aspx is made - if it's not a.aspx or b.aspx you can redirect the user away.

Answer (score 0):

As menitoned previously you need to check the current UrlReferrer, here is an example in vb.net

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim bRedirect As Boolean = True
    Try
        If Not IsNothing(Page.Request.UrlReferrer) Then
            Dim sReferer As String = Page.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
            If sReferer.Contains("/a.aspx") Or sReferer.Contains("/b.aspx") Then
                bRedirect = False
            End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Raise exception, decide whether or not to redirect
    End Try
    If bRedirect Then
        Response.Redirect("~/x.aspx", True)
    End If
End Sub
```